# Jquery Facebox plugin does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, lightbox

Using the plugin from: [Famspam's Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox)
however I seem to be encountering some issues getting it to open. The following is my head contents:

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Prepotence</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="/src/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <link href="/src/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="/src/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
    loadingImage : '/src/loading.gif',
    closeImage   : '/src/closelabel.png'
   })
  })
 </script>
</head>
```

And whenever I attempt to open anything with code similar to:

```
<a href="blah.php" rel="facebox">Link</a>
```

Absolutely nothing shows up, at all.

Comment: i have used that plugin, it was crap 2 years ago and its still crap. stick with jquery ui dialog

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage : '/src/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : '/src/closelabel.png'
    });
});
```

I've checked it and it's working fine, you can change both `$` to `jQuery` if you're using other frameworks $-related :)

Cheers

G.